# pepper pest problem

Tags: pest-control, pests, peppers, pesticide

can anyone help me out with the problem on the pictures? One of the pictures shows a bio insecticide I allready tried twice, but it doesn't help.

I don't know what kind of pest it is nor what I can do to remove it. It regards pepper plants, I took inside to overwinter. I am hoping to put them in my greenhouse when it gets warm enough and get some nice peppers of them like last year.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Update: Trying to find out the color of the flies I took a new picture; I found another critter; maybe these are aphids? I am not at home right now, but this evening I will check again if I can find out the color of the flies. To be honest, I think the original pest is indeed some sort of white fly.

[image]

Update: I checked again...I don't see any white flies fly away when I get close. I do see white/yellow non flying bugs; I think those are aphids. The white dots on the leaves in the pictures are already dead...I think also aphids, but I am not sure. I also noticed black flies above the ground. They fly away/crawl around when disturbed. I think those are fungus gnats. I guess I'll just give my plants another shower of my bio insecticide, :-(

Comment: Have you tried to give the plant a quick shower? The photos are a bit blurry, but they _might_ be already dead.

Comment: I mixed the bio inseticide with water and indeed gave the plant a shower, but I see some move, so they are not all dead

Comment: Ah. Thanks for the update. So it seems your insecticide does work at least a bit.

Comment: What color are the live ones? Do any of them fly when disturbed?

Comment: I will check again this evening for the color of the flies...for more details...I updated my post.

Answer (score 2):

I always like to add that the soap will kill them on contact, so you can rinse the plant thoroughly immediately after treatment.

Answer (score 1):

Silverleaf Whitfly 
Update:  as well as aphids 
they lay eggs on the underside of the leaves 
and if you disturb them they fly away

don't use any chemical sprays as they become used to it and if only makes problems worse.

1 teaspoon liquid soap 
1 litre of clean water 
optional ( one drop of neem oil)

make a soapy water solution using nontoxic washing up liquid and water 
spray all over the plant even underneath every leaf 
if the plant is outside the rain will flush all the soap away otherwise just rinse it afterwards.

to deal with the adults you need to use yellosticky paper traps as they get stuck for good.